# how to access database API to fetch the records

Tags: database, api, grails

I am using grails and as my projects requirement I want to store companies database in my own project database.In order to do that I want to use companies database api's, but i don't know much about database api's.Can someone suggest me a way.thanks in advance..

Comment: Please provide a concrete problem with code you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr: build a REST service to deal with the other data source**

I was having similar scenario, so let me tell that if it can help you.

*scenario:*

In the company I work for, we are building a Grails app for another company (lets call it **company_b**). So **company_b** has its own data warehouse and they want to push some of the data to the application I built.

**N.B** has its own developers.

*The solution I came up with:*

Looking at their database I designed the appropriate tables, and shared my db schema with the developers on **company_b**, then I build kind of REST API to expose the tables I designed( the domain objects). So then the developers on **company_b** developed an API to consume the rest API I built and they are now able to send any record or any operation(delete,update,etc..).

I used json, its structure looks like this.

```
{
    "user": {
        "username":"username",
        "password":"password"
    },
    "operation":"INSERT",
    "objectName":"Employee",
    "objectId":"employeeId",
    "object": {
        "employeeId":"1212",
        "phoneNumber":"0923335227",
        "dateOfBirth":"12/7/1982"
    }
}
```

Look at the **user object** above ^.

The requests that come to consume the REST API are skipped from the spring authentication and I use the **user object** to manually authenticate each request.

*I hope it will give you some insight, but this might not be the right fit for your scenario. Refer the web a lot docs out there.*